# Python 2.7 Append results from multiple 'if' statements to a single list. Works correctly only on first if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, append, cursor

I'm trying to populate an empty list with new formatted labels for map use and exporting to a table. The format needs to be different for different regions (defined by the first two digits in ADMIN_ORG). The labels I need to format are in the ID field.

The first 'if' statement (startswith '04') seems to print correct results. My next 'elif' statement (startswith '10') does not work right. The code using labels.extend is adding in data but only one character at a time to the list.

Example input:

```
'D','O','U','G','L','A','S','_','H','I','G', 'H', 'W','A','Y','6','5','4'
```

Output should be like this

```
'DOUGLAS_HIGHWAY' OR '654'
```

I have also tried using labels.append for the next 'elif' but it doesn't append anything from that 'elif'.

I need to have at least 12 or so different 'if' iterations for my labels list.

What am I missing?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import re, string, time
from string import ascii_letters

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
start = time.time()

#********DATA AND PATHS********

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Labels.mxd')
fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'RoadCore_Existing')[0]

fields = ['ID', 'ADMIN_ORG']
labels = []

def newlabel():
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as sc:
        for row in sc:
            if row[1].startswith('04'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(row[0].replace("-ADMIN","").replace('-A-ADMIN','').replace('-PARKING','')[2:].lstrip('0').replace('.', '-').lstrip(ascii_letters)))
            elif row[1].startswith('10'):
                labels.extend('{}'.format(row[0].lstrip('0').replace('.', '-')))#.lstrip(ascii_letters)))
            #else:
                #labels.extend(row[0])
    print(labels)
```

Comment: Maybe you should debug your `row` to see what really appens

Comment: @NoeXWolf I'm fairly new at python and was reviewing the printed output on command line to check what appends. How would you do the debug?

Comment: Thanks @Midavalo I tried using a second append initially  but it didn't add that data for second if statemnet  '10'.... it still had only the data from the first '04' if statement. I assumed it would be fine to have several appends

Comment: use append instead of extend - the value you are trying to write is a string, so labels.extend will add the values one character at a time to your list. Append will add the string to the list.

Comment: Your cursor here, and how it outputs info, is specific to `arcpy` and you are likely to get answers from people familiar with arcpy at [gis.se] Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

This portion of the script was solved. Using multiple appends was the answer. Having a similar issue now with exporting the list to csv.